# How to description 3 nouns in a sentence?

Tags: nouns

I want to describe ' Please enter the input value of temperature with numerical in the form.'

But input, value and temperature also are nouns, how can I joint it together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Input value" is perfectly fine. In that combination, "input" is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

But if you want to get people to just fill in what temperature they are measuring, I would write something along the lines of

> Please enter the temperature numerically

or if "input value" refers to some system that controls the temperature, then maybe

> Please enter the input value for the temperature